# IntelliJ does not export to exe

Tags: intellij-idea, build, exe

I have seen many guides where artifacts menu contains `Native bundle` field. But I don't have it. Moreover, after building the project, the EXE file doesn't appear in any folder. [See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbMPE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The option is there but the bottom panel hides it. Please resize the panel and you get the option back. There is similar report on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183544